# POST Request - Firebase -Response for preflight is invalid (redirect) - CORS

Tags: angularjs, http, post, firebase, ionic-framework

I am trying to post into a Slack channel from an Ionic app, however i am being blocked by the following error in the browser..

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load  http://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX. 
Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

I believe I have narrowed this down to amending the firebase.json file, and am trying to amend the headers to allow CORS within this file.

```
headers: [ {
5     source : **/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff),
4     headers : [ {
3       key: Access-Control-Allow-Origin,
2       value: *
1     } ]
16     }, {
1     source : **/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff),
2     headers : {  [
3       key: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,
4       value: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
5   } ]
6   }]
7 }
```

I would greatly appreciate any thoughts on how I might get this working.  I am basing my amendments on the following.

http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/full-config.html

Comment: I think the problem is that http://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX isn't sending CORS headers, not the site on Firebase Hosting (if it's an ionic app, do you even have any static assets there?). Give `https` a try instead of `http` and it might work, though that depends a lot on the service

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue with the very same message.

After some debugging I realized that the site that I was trying to request used HSTS ([HTTP-Strict-Transport-Security](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)), so the browser automatically redirected every HTTP request to HTTPS, breaking the preflight request.

Take into consideration that HSTS can be cached for a very long time on your browser so it won't help clearing cache or other methods. You can check at `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` if you are using Chrome to check if this is affecting you.

The solution was to ensure that only HTTPS requests were being made from the application wanting to do CORS.

Hope this helps!

---

Comment: Hi @llekn can you please tell me how do you fix the issue?

Comment: As I said on my answer, the solution was to make only HTTPS requests